# angular input ng-bind not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind

this is the code:

```
        <span>{{ vm.GetSalaryItemValue(salaryItem,detail) }}</span>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" data-ng-bind="vm.GetSalaryItemValue(salaryItem,detail)" />
        <textarea  class="form-control" data-ng-bind="vm.GetSalaryItemValue(salaryItem,detail)" rows="1"
                    ng-blur="vm.SalaryItemValueChanged($event,salaryItem,detail)"></textarea>
```

span and textarea are working correctly and shows value, 
but input tag not working and display nothing.
(span and textarea are for testing only)
(salaryItem,detail are passing correctly), 
if I change ng-bind to ng-model, value will be displayed but an error will be throw.

any idea?

Comment: What error do you get in ng-model?

Comment: ng-bind is not the same as ng-model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want one way binding to a textbox's value, i.e. from a calculated function, use [ng-value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue). Just be warned that any input placed in there will not be able to be read. This is only really useful for a readonly or disabled textbox where you don't need 2-way binding.

Comment: question is :why textarea is working correctly but input not?

Comment: Because ng-bind binds the "inner HTML" of the tag. Inner HTML refers to what is between the begin and end tags, i.e. <tag>this is inner HTML</tag>. Input and textarea work differently, in terms of where the dynamic content is stored. The input tag is <input value="stuff" /> so it has no inner HTML and you must use ng-value or ng-model to interact with the value attribute. The textarea tag is <textarea>stuff</textarea> so it has inner HTML that can be bound using ng-bind.

Comment: Plus one to both the question and answer in the above comments.

Answer (score 3):

Change the input code to use `ng-model` instead `ng-bind` and assign the output of `vm.GetSalaryItemValue(salaryItem,detail)` to a scope variable:

```
<div ng-init="inputNumber = vm.GetSalaryItemValue(salaryItem,detail)"></div>
<input type="number" class="form-control" data-ng-model="inputNumber" />
```

You need to assign the scope variable because `ng-model` cannot execute the function.

Comment: This is the error you're producing with your code: `"Error: [ngModel:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/ngModel/nonassign?p0=getName()&p1=%3Cinput"lass%3D%22ng-pristine%20ng-untouched%20ng-valid%22%20ng-model%3D%22getName()%22%20type%3D%22text%22%3E`

Comment: I need to calculate value on the fly based on the parameters, and inputs are generated, so there is no variable to bind to (I mean I cant generate variable for every input)

Comment: textarea is working correctly, input has a problem (it's probably a bug)

Comment: No there isn't a bug. You are mixing the usage of ng-bind and ng-model. Ng-bind evaluates an expression to set the text value of an element whilst ng-model binds to a property in the corresponding controller. You're using an expression to bind to ng-model and desperately wishing it would work.

Comment: it's working with "Textarea" as i mentioned, problem is "Input",  if i change TextArea to input, it stop working.  and where i used ng-model exactly? if you look at example i'm using ng-blur (focus-out), so read more carefully